# Visual Studio 2012 Express: Browser returning 500 status trying to download jsx file

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

I am following this tutorial: http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html and using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

```
<body>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx")"></script>
</body>
```

I have `Tutorial.jsx` in my `Scripts` folder in the same project still I am getting 500 status error in console on google chrome.

But when I try to change it to:

```
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Tutorial.js"></script>
</body>
```

`Tutorial.js` is also in `Scripts` folder and chrome downloads it and its working fine.

I want to use jsx file only.

Comment: Can you share the exact error? I think it's a mime-type issue.

Comment: http://localhost:51175/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: i'm pretty sure i've got the same issue. for some reason the jsx path is being resolved as /username/some_folder/wwwroot/username/some_folder/wwwroot/tutorial.jsx

actually, i'll reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We experienced the same problem.

We solved our problem changing the **build action** property of the .jsx file from `none` to `content`

[image: image1]
[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the jsx file via the first example you mentioned, that's not working, you must have that file in the proper folder as shown here.

***Location of JSX file***

[image]

Typically; however, a 500 error may mean something else is wrong.  Open your project and verify you have these packages.. found in the packages.config file.

***Packages Needed***

[image]

*Finally*
   The project needs to be created as a empty MVC project *with* MVC folders.  This allows you to create the controller to serve up the index file.

***Index File***

```html
 @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx")"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Home Controller***

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

***Debugging***

Navigate to the page, press F12, press Console button and look to see if there's any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm having the same issue. whenever i hit my .jsx file, i get a 500 error. through the terminal i can see that it's an error through the React/Babel loader. For whatever reason the path that is passed to the function is:

/path/that/contains/scriptfolder/path/that/contains/scriptfolder/Scripts/1.jsx

which doesn't make a lot of sense to me, here is the output:

```
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx  
      fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not find a part of the path 
         "/home/pete/code/ReactExample/wwwroot/home/pete/code/ReactExample/wwwroot
          /Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx".


      System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
          "/home/pete/code/ReactExample/wwwroot/home/pete/code/ReactExample/wwwroot
           /Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx".
```

So it clearly cannot find the file because it's using a stupid path. This is coming straight from the React code:

```
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
 <0x7fcead751600 + 0x00031> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string,
System.Text.Encoding)
    at System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding 
encoding) <0x7fcead8e0610 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at React.FileSystemBase.ReadAsString (System.String relativePath)
 <0x4027ffb0 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at React.Babel.TransformFileWithSourceMap (System.String filename,
 Boolean forceGenerateSourceMap) <0x403d45c0 + 0x000d5> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at React.Babel.TransformFile (System.String filename) <0x403d4590 + 0x0001a> 
in <filename unknown>:0 
    at React.AspNet.BabelFileSystem+BabelFileInfo+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>
b__0 () <0x403d4510 + 0x0005e> in <filename unknown>:0
```

now as to why it's doing this i have no idea. I know it's not the web container, as there's also a file hello.html there which is sent back to the browser succesfully. There must be a setting or something in Startup.cs that I've forgotten to set, or perhaps forgotten to comment out.